# Square brackets around vs after expression in Typescript

Tags: typescript

is there a difference between the following two square bracket notations in Typescript?
Tried a couple of scenarios and it seems they are equivalent?

Thank you!

```
interface test {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

const x: test[] = [{a: "aaaa", b: "bbbb"}]

const y: [test] = [{a: "aaaa", b: "bbbb"}]
```

Comment: It's an array vs a tuple. The two are not equivalent *except* in exactly this one case you've shown here.

Comment:   Now I see, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As @VLAZ pointd out, x is an [Array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array), while y is a [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

The difference is observable even in this simple case.

```
interface test {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

const x: test[] = [{a: "aaaa", b: "bbbb"}]
const y: [test] = [{a: "aaaa", b: "bbbb"}]

x.push({a: "a1", b: "b1"});  // works fine
y.push({a: "a1", b: "b1"});  // works fine

const a = x[1]; // works fine 
const b = y[1]; // compilation error 
                // Tuple type '[test]' of length '1' has no element at index '1'.
```

Comment: indeed, thanks for elaborating on the example!